# Efficiency of this constantly running time processor for an HTML5 video control bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I built a custom HTML5 video control bar, and for each second, it updates two readings:

1. Time Elapsed
2. Time Remaining

in hh:mm:ss notation, like so:

[image]

Because of how often this function runs, I want it to be as efficient as possible.

[I created this JS Fiddle to test benchmarks.](http://jsfiddle.net/jtodd/VY6qy/4/) It runs the timer normally, until you un-comment the benchmark and comment the casual running func. *The commented function call runs this function 1,000,000 times and logs the speed via the console's timing utility.*

**I'm looking for best practices, efficiency, and general improvements.**

---

Here's the code. For testing, it's been modified to run in a loop or at a set interval rather than being connected to a video.

```
/* Video Time Processing Benchmark Snippet */

var timeProgress = $("#time-progress"),
    timeRemaining = $("#time-remaining");

// Set mock video duration for testing
var duration = 5000;

// Convert numbers to double+ digit format (09, 99, 999)
function digitize(n) {
    return n > 9 ? "" + n : "0" + n;
}

// Convert seconds to hh:mm:ss
function secondsToHMS(seconds) {
    var numhours = digitize(Math.floor(((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) / 3600));
    var numminutes = digitize(Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) / 60));
    var numseconds = digitize(Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60));
    return numhours + ":" + numminutes + ":" + numseconds;
}

// Process the elapsed and remaining times to two hh:mm:ss format
function processTime(currentTime) {
    var value = (100 / duration) * currentTime;
    var progressHMS = secondsToHMS(currentTime);
    var remainingHMS = "-" + secondsToHMS(duration - currentTime);
    timeProgress.html(progressHMS);
    timeRemaining.html(remainingHMS);
}

// Test time via interval or loop
function testTime(type, number) {
    if (type == "interval") {

        // If a number isn't provided, the default is every second (1000)
        if (!number) var number = 1000;
        var i = 0;

        // Set interval to run function
        setInterval(function(){
            currentTime = i;
            processTime(currentTime);
            i++;

            // Clear the interval when duration is reached
            if (i > duration) clearInterval(Int);
        }, number);
    }
    else if (type == "loop"){
        for (var i = 0; i < duration; i++){
            currentTime = i;
            processTime(currentTime);
        }
    }
}

// Use Int to set time for clearInterval() targetng
var Int = testTime("interval");

//Get benchamark on functon, vs optimized versions
/*
console.time("Benchmark");
    testTime("loop", 1000000);
console.timeEnd("Benchmark");
*/
```

Comment: Don't use `setInterval` to animate, use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame). This allows the browser to decide when to reanimate and sync it with general repainting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're worried about performance, this should raise a red flag:

```
someJQueryObject = $("#some-id");
...
someJQueryObject.html(aPlainOldString);
```

`.html(foo)` is almost certainly slower than `.innerHTML = foo`, because `.html()` does a bunch of [extra stuff](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L404), like checking if it can use innerHTML, trying to use innerHTML, catching errors if that fails and using a fallback, etc. Also, using innerHTML is probably slower than simply creating a [Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-1312295772) node and updating its `data` property.

I'd suggest replacing `timeProgress = $("#time-progress")` with something like this:

```
var timeProgress = document.createTextNode('');

document.getElementById('time-progress').appendChild(timeProgress);
```

And replacing `timeProgress.html(progressHMS);` with this:

```
timeProgress.data = progressHMS;
```

This will be a significant performance improvement and will also eliminate the jQuery dependency. Using a large GP library like jQuery to select two elements and update their text content seems like overkill anyway.

[Here's a jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/code-review-question-58549/4) demonstrating the performance difference.

Comment: [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/code-review-question-58549/2). Wow, this is way faster! I had to use `document.createTextNode("");` though.

Comment: @Schism good catch, updated with the empty string. Interesting perf. :)

Comment: Whoooops, the property is `data`, not `value`. No wonder it went so fast. I just perfed it and it's still way faster though.

Comment: I have to admit, while the other answers are valuable, this one mostly clearly demonstrates a performance increase. +1 and check.

Comment: @Schism could you update your JSPerf-Link to the newest revision, which includes the fix: http://jsperf.com/code-review-question-58549/4

Comment: @Falco I'd love to but I can't; comments can only be edited in the first five minutes. I've edited it into the question.

Answer (score 9):

When converting time values like this I find it much simpler, and more readable to work up from the smallest units. Consider the following:

```
// Convert seconds to hh:mm:ss
function secondsToHMS(intime) {
    var numseconds = digitize(intime % 60);
    intime = Math.floor(intime / 60);
    var numminutes = digitize(intime % 60);
    intime = Math.floor(intime / 60);
    var numhours = digitize(intime);
    return numhours + ":" + numminutes + ":" + numseconds;
}
```

The intime variable is modified as the time runs through. It first counts seconds, then minutes, then hours.

as for the performance, I imagine it is faster because the calculations are fewer, and simpler, but I have not benchmarked it. Even if it is not faster, I would still prefer it.

Comment: [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/code-review-question-58549). About the same speed, but this is more readable.

Comment: Thanks @Schism - on my machine (Firefox), my solution came out ahead by 15%

Answer (score 6):

- I (like many others) prefix my jQuery object variables with a `$` to make `$timeProgress` and `$timeRemaining`. To me, this is a nice explicit reminder that they're jQuery objects, à la [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).
- `duration` seems to me like it could be better named `totalTime` or something.
- In `digitize()`, I see little point in doing `"" + n`. Use `return (n > 9 ? "" : "0") + n` or `return n > 9 ? n : "0" + n`.
- I know that you stripped out your code, but here, you don't use `value` in `processTime()`.
- In `testTime()`, you aren't actually passing through the return value of `setInterval`, so you won't be able to go and `clearInterval` with `Int` (which, incidentally, should be lowercased renamed to something like `testIntervalHandle` or something).
- Not that it'll matter in production/release, but you're polluting global namespace with `currentTime` in `testTime()`.

Finally, I don't imagine performance is as crucial as you make it out to be; once per second is pretty lenient.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that performance may not be a issue at all. This is basically an animation set to run at 1 fps - that should be doable :)

Comment: +1 for formatting, naming, and namespace, but most of all because I didn't realize that once per second mattered so little. However, perhaps learning the most efficient method in situations like this, where it hardly matters, will prepare me (and maybe even you?) for a situation where a similar thing needs to be done much faster than this.